# Accessing text of textfield from content_cls of MDDialog and pass it to a function

Tags: python, kivymd

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: city
        hint_text: "City"

    MDTextField:
        id: street
        hint_text: "Street"


MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    
                    MDFlatButton(
                                    text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                                    on_press= lambda x, city_name = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.city.text : self.print_city(city_name)
                                ),
                    
                    MDFlatButton(text = "print",               
                                 on_press= lambda x, street_name= self.dialog.content_cls.ids.city.text : self.print_street(street_name)
                                ),
                        ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
    
    
    
    def print_city(city_name):
        print(city_name)

    def print_street(street_name):
        print(street_name)



Example().run()
```

how can i  get text from  self.dialog.content_cls.ids.city.text   and  pass it  to  self.print_city

is it possible
if not then please let me know the another way to done

i am tring to create billing software  . to get the user input through MDDialog  for quantity value

thanks in advance
sorry for the broken eng

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing values during instantiation of the dialog. This may result in error. What you actually need to do is passing the values after the dialog is created (and here when user presses 'Print').

Change the lines,

```py
                    MDFlatButton(text = "[b]Print",               
                                 on_press= lambda x, street_name= self.dialog.content_cls.ids.city.text : self.print_street(street_name)
                                ),
```

with the following,

```py
                    MDFlatButton(text = "[b]Print",               
                                 on_press=self.print_street,
                                ),
```

Then in `print_street`,

```py
    def print_street(self, btn):
        street_name = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.street.text
        print(street_name)
```

Similar applies for other.

Comment: oh! thank you  MR ApuCoder  last 3 hours it driving me crazy  finally i get it